# How to delete provisioning profile with Apple Free/Personnal licence

Tags: xcode, ios-provisioning

I have created an apple account. It is a free account that permits me to install my iOS app on my own devices.

I have an error in Xcode: "Unable to add device 'XXXXX' because the team has already reached the maximum number of iPhone devices.".

My question is: how can i remove devices or provisioning profiles on this free account ? Everything is managed by Xcode. There is no web portal. Thanks

Comment: Did your Apple account used to be a paid developer account? I think I've seen this with developers who let their paid account expire, and then tried to use it as a free account.

Comment: No it is not used to be a paid account, it is a free account...

Comment: Have you used the free account to build to more than 100 devices?

Comment: no i don't used more that 100 devices